# Call an event in a page from a separate usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I am fairly new to WPF and C# programming, most of my prior work was in winforms and vb.net. Before I can ask my question, here is some background to explain what I am trying o achieve. I have a fairly simple application that is designed to read books, however there are several "views" required, for which I am using pages hosted in a frame within my main window. One of my "pages" has a child usercontrol called settings, basically when a user clicks on a setting (such as to show or hide an item or element hosted in the parent "page" (NOT the mainwindow) or call an event on the "page". I would like to know how to achieve that, I have spent days looking for a solution to this problem. Some sample code etc would also be a valuable help.

Comment: can you provide some graphics to explain what you are trying to achieve please?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want your "page" to be updated from what you'll do in your child user control?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, page must be updated from the child user control. So if a toggle is set on the usercontrol to control visibility of the item on the page, then the page item gets set to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a look at the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern. It's a pattern to seperate your business logic from the UI with an intermediate layer (the ViewModel) which manages your application state, etc. Your UI communicates with the ViewModel via DataBinding mechanisms, which are quite sophisticated. You'll find heaps of information on all of these topics.

To point you in the right direction: You will have a ViewModel which holds all state information for your UI, such as what items to display. Your UserControl is bound to the ViewModel in a way that it toggles a visibility flag of an item, for example. The 'page' is bound to that same property and sets the visibility of the item accordingly.

My advice: WPF is a very, very complex and very, very powerful system. There is no real point in using it without MVVM and an according software architecture. You don't learn WPF/MVVM in a couple of days, probably not even weeks. You should start with the basic concepts, maybe get a book and forget about your concrete problems for a while. It's worth it, though. If you don't have the time for this, stick to what you know, it will be frustrating otherwise...

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, will look into that, appreciate the feedback

Comment: Problem solved. Have implemented a decent MVVM pattern and app is functioning just the way I want! Thanks fr your assistance